# Quel est le sens et l'origine de fériés dans l'expression « jours fériés » ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie

Quel est le sens et l'origine de **fériés** dans l'expression « jours fériés » ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'après le dictionnaire de l'Académie,c'est un jour de fête:

> XIIe siècle, feirié, foirié. Issu du latin chrétien feriatus, « (jour)
>   de fête ». N'est guère usité que dans l'expression Jour férié, jour où
>   l'on ne travaille pas, en raison d'une prescription religieuse, d'une
>   disposition légale. En France, le dimanche est un jour férié. Ce
>   magasin est fermé le dimanche et les autres jours fériés ou, ellipt.,
>   les dimanches et jours fériés.

Answer (score 1):

Le [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/feriee) a une section étymologie pour le mot qui le fait remonter au latin *ferior, feriari* « être en fête, chômer ».

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour!
J'ai fait une petite recherche de l'origine du mot « férié », qui est apparu au XIIe siècle en période de civilisation musulmane en Espagne andalouse. Le mot « feria » en espagnol est synonyme de mot « ferha » (فرحة) en arabe qui veut dire joie et bonheur. On trouve encore le mot « ferhad » (فرهد) en dialecte tunisien qui veut dire bien être et joie.
Le latin « feriatus » a été adapté du même mot.
J'ai trouvé une autre origine du mot qui vient du jour de la fête juive des 14 et 15 mars en commémoration d'un événement religieux du XIe siècle av. JC (sauvés après des annèes de persécutions par l'empereur perse): le mot en hébreu "bourem" puis arabisé plus tard en فهر feria. Je précise que les juifs étaient très présents en Espagne andalouse et qu'ils occupaient des postes importants de l'état.

Comment: Votre réponse a été corrigée mais il reste des choses anormales dont le correcteur ne peut pas décider pour vous.

Answer (score 0):

### Étymologiquement, férié vient du latin "ferie, feria" qui signifie jour de repos.

Culturellement, je crois que nous lions particulièrement cet adjectif au mot foire. Auparavant les jours les plus importants dans les villages et villes étaient les jours de foire qui étaient la source des principaux échanges commerciaux mais aussi de diversion. Ces jours étaient eux-mêmes liés à un saint. Par exemple, à Annecy dont je suis originaire, la principale foire est la Foire de la Saint André.

Comment: Cela mériterait une référence, car c'est pas si évident je trouve que le 15 aout, par exemple, soit associé aux jours de foire du moyen âge. Mais vous avez raison qu'il y a un changement de sens du mot _foire_... c'est assez compliqué, et c'est pour ça qu'il me semble important d'avoir une confirmation et/ou précision. Cordialement.

Comment: *mais aussi de diversion* ?

Comment: @Istao, le 15 août est le jour du solstice d'été qui était fêté du temps des romains.

Comment: Le 15 aout = solstice d'ete ?  Et le 21 juin, alors ?